# Python OO in Jupyter notebook, object doesn't reinitialize

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop, jupyter

I don't know if this is a product of Jupyter, Python or my lack of knowledge on object oriented programming but I have created a Genetic Algorithm optimizer which I am developing inside a Jupyter notebook. Everything is working fine, however when I rerun a cell which generates the Optimizer object and then call the optimize function it will (sometimes) not overwrite the object with the new settings. I am thoroughly confused, anyone know what could cause this? Here is the contents of the cell:

```
optimization = GeneticOptimization(Fitness(sum), 500, 50, initializer=100)
top_member, top_fitness, fitness_values = optimization.optimize(verbose=True)
```

When I restart the kernel or sometimes when I run some other cells it will update it. The verbosity and changing the initializer value (number of bits/genes in a chromosome) show whether it has updated or not.

*Edit:*

Small example of what is happening inside GeneticOptimization:

Cell 1:

```
def get_number(number):
    if isinstance(number,int):
        return number
    elif isinstance(number,str):
        return int(number)
    else:
        raise ValueError('No valid number returned')

class Test:
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = get_number(number)

    def print_number(self):
        print self.number
```

Cell 2:

```
test = Test('132')
test.print_number()
```

So it would sometimes print old values when rerunning Cell 2, however not in this small case.

Comment: You do know that the subsequent cells that read variables changed from this current cell you just re-ran, do not update automatically right? (i.e. you have to run the subsequent cells on the new values to get an updated output from them) I'm noting this because it often throws me off, so I try to rerun the whole notebook just to be sure I'm not looking at outdated outputs

Comment: Yes, I use notebooks a lot, anytime I finalize a change in a cell I always rerun it if necessary, I've never experienced this before but this is the first time I'm really using an OO approach within Notebooks

Comment: If you can post a minimal notebook that can reproduce this I'm sure we can find the problem. There's a very good chance you will figure it out on your own if you do that too!

Comment: I cannot get it reproduced in a constructed way, it doesn't always happen either. I updated the question with a very small structure of what is basically happening in the objects

Comment: Maybe somewhere in the actual code you are using a global and not a variable that is encapsulated in the classe's state (e.g. you forgot `self` in `self.var` and `var` happens to be accessible by accident, e.g. a global or a variable visible from a previous cell). You could unit test your class first too that would eliminate some bugs before we even consider the notebook issues.

Comment: Good suggestion and will look into it, but that wouldn't explain the stochastic/random nature of the problem. Thanks for thinking along!